# Как создать несколько пустых pandas фреймов данных?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть список названий для будущих таблиц names = ["a","b",...]. Как инициализировать len(names) пустых фреймов пандас, чтобы каждый из них имел имя a, b ... соответственно. То есть вместо:
a=pd.DataFrame()

d=pd.DataFrame()

c=pd.DataFrame()

d=pd.DataFrame()

e=pd.DataFrame()

я хочу как-то одним циклом/командой это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй создать словарь и добавь туда эти фреймы

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: df_dict = dict(('df_' + str(x), pd.DataFrame()) for x in N)
for dfi in df_dict:
  print(dfi)
принт выводит список имен, а не сами фреймы

Comment: @ДмитрийРедько Учите основы работы со словарями. По умолчанию словарь отдаёт ключи. Хотите значения - берите `.values()`, хотите пары ключ-значение - берите `.items()` от словаря.

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать такой способ:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['a','b','c']
d = dict.fromkeys(names, pd.DataFrame())
```

результат:

```
{'a': Empty DataFrame
      Columns: []
      Index: [],
 'b': Empty DataFrame
      Columns: []
      Index: [],
 'c': Empty DataFrame
      Columns: []
      Index: []}
```